# Efforts made on closed questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

Questions closed as exact-duplicates are not prepared on purpose.

It is just the variety of words used to describe a same question. Can Stack Exchange provide a way(can be algorithm or manual effort) to find the questions that are conceptually or contextually the same.

Comment: There *are* efforts. When the title of a question is typed, a set of similar questions shows up beneath. We can't help it if this is being ignored. Algorithmically, there isn't much else that can be done, until computers can process natural language much better than they currently can.

Comment: Why did you remove the majority of your question and exactly those parts being answered below?

Comment: lots of downvotes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> a vain effort for the person who prepared the question

How so? The person still gets the answer, it's just not directly attached to the question she posted.

> a vain effort for the persons who answered this closed question

Not really; duplicate questions are often not deleted (see [Do not delete good duplicates!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates)), so they get to keep any votes and accept marks on their answers. The answers still exist, and can still be edited and continuously voted on.

If one of the answerers would really like to ensure that his post is not deleted in the case that the closed question is, the answer can be moved to the "master" question. The answerer can either flag to ask a moderator to merge the two questions, or he can manually delete and repost, after editing for specifics like variable names.

Answer (score 4):

While more explicit notification of duplicate identification has been requested: [Duplicate notification while writing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22907/duplicate-notification-while-writing-an-answer)

...I think we're already nearly there without having to support it explicitly. If someone votes to close a question as a duplicate, a comment will automatically be created on behalf of the voter, linking to the original question. Anyone with the page open in their (supported) browser at that time will receive notification of this (albeit subtly, in the form of a "show 1 more comments" message below the question). If you watch for this, you'll know before posting your answer that the question is possibly a duplicate, and will be able to account for this.